# Showing that $\mathscr{L}$ is not context-free-grammar language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

> Let $"t"$ and $"s"$ be a words we will say that two words are "completly different" if for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant |t|$ the $i$ letter in $t$ diffrent from the $i$ letter in $s$.
>
> Prove that the language $\mathcal{L}=\{ts|t,s\in \{0,1\}^*,|t|=|s|,t,s \text{   completly different} \}$ is not a free-context-language

*Attempt :*

Applaying the pumping lemma for free-contex-language:

Suppose that $\mathcal L$ is regular so exists a word '$z=uxvyw$' with length of at least $n$ such that:

$(1)\,\,\,|xvy|\leqslant n$

$(2)\,\,\,|xy|\geqslant 1$

$(3)\,\,\,ux^ivy^iw \in \mathcal L\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,i\geqslant 0$

Now, let's choose the word $\color{blue}{z=0^n1^n}$ it is obvious that $|z|\geqslant n$ so we can use $(1)-(3)$

$z=0^{\alpha}0^{\beta}0^{\gamma}0^{\lambda}1^n$

So $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\lambda=n$

I am stuck here.

---

> EDIT: After using @Renato's answer:

Consider $z=0^p1^p0^p1^p0^p1^p\in \mathcal{L}$ since $|z|>p$, there are $u,v,w,x,y$ such that $z=uvwxy,|vwx|\leqslant p, |vx|>0$ and $uv^iwx^iy\in \mathcal{L}$

$vwx$ must straddle the midpoint of $z$ there are fore possibilities:

- $vwx$ is in $0^p$ part.
- $vwx$ is in $1^p$ part.
- $vwx$ is in $1^p0^p$ part.
- $vwx$ is in $0^p1^p$ part.

Thus, it is not of the form that we want

For $i=2$ $z\notin \mathcal{L}$

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't give us much of an attempt to work with. Plus, your ansatz is flawed already; be more careful reading the theorem! I recommend you check out our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) and *just try out some candidate words*. Seeing what works and what does not, you gain experience that helps you picking suitable words faster.

Comment: Your attempt is still incomplete. Have you *read* the reference question? You have to prove for *all* partitionings of the word as per the PL that something bad happens.

Comment: By the way, community votes please: is this a duplicate of the reference question? As long as the problem is "please explain the Pumping lemma to me", it provides an elaborate answer.

Comment: @Raphael yes, I read the referance question, it is almost like to read in wikipedia about the pumping lemma.

Comment: So? To be blunt, I'm afraid that if you don't understand these resources, you won't understand answers either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong because you can pump in the middle of the word. A guy has commited the same mistake as you yesterday. Check this answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/51613/31129

Comment: It is the same answer that I linked. Take your time to read that post. You will have to put a little effort of your side. You will have to put a little effort of your side. Our idea is that you learn something not solving homeworks.

Comment: You are choosing a decomposition for $z$. That is wrong too. You have to prove that the decomposition does not exist to get the contradiction. If you read the answer I linked you can easily think of a decomposition so your word $z=a^nb^n$ is useless. You will have to try another word or try to generate a PDA to prove that $\mathscr{L}$ is CFL.

Comment: It's seems that the word works fine but It is unnecessarily complex. I would use $\sigma=1^p0^p0^p1^p$ instead and remember that you have to explain why the four posibilities do not work.